# How to convert a/p (am/pm) time value in python to 24hr format

Tags: python-3.x, time

I am reading a `csv` file which has a time field as `3:50a` and `4:25p`. I need to convert this time values to 24 hour clock format as `H:M` for this I am doing:

```
datetime.strptime(str(time_value), '%I:%M').strftime('%H:%M')
```

where `time_value` is `3:50a` or `4:25p`. Now the problem is above line of code do not work because I have not inlucded the `AM/PM` tag which is `%p` in `%I:%M` and that is because in the `csv` file I am just getting `a` for `AM` and `p` for `PM`.

How can I deal with this situation. I need to convert the time_value to 24hr clock format. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `'m'` to the string you input to `strptime` and put the `%p` in its second argument,

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> time_value = '3:50a'
>>> datetime.strptime(str(time_value)+'m', '%I:%M%p').strftime('%H:%M')
'03:50'
>>> time_value = '4:25p'
>>> datetime.strptime(str(time_value)+'m', '%I:%M%p').strftime('%H:%M')
'16:25'
```